# Override template file i subfolders

Tags: theme-development, themes, templates, child-theme, template-hierarchy

What is the correct way to override theme template files in subfolders with a child theme?

I wan't to override a theme template file with the following path:
/components/theme-header/

Do I have to create the same path in the child theme or just place the overriding template file with the same name in the root of the child theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the child theme should have the file to override the parent theme in the same location.  So yes in the same sub-folder location.